# How to pass argument from one re-occurring workflow to another

Tags: scheduled-tasks, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm using a third-party solution, that effectively offers a limited MWF interface when it comes to Workflow development.
The challenge I have is that I am trying to utilise the workflow scheduling interface, that would allow me to have workflows re-occurring at prescribed times/dates etc.  No problem here.  However, due to the underlying data, I need to store a key to this data in the initiating workflow, which is then accessible to all subsequent "child" workflows.  I've tried setting an Argument field, In/Out & In, in the workflow, but this is not preserved in subsequent iterations.  Any solutions?  Thanks

Comment: Is storing the key in a database and then retrieving it when the workflows start not an option?

Comment: Don't think so, as suppose I have 3 reoccurring entries, rows if you wish, each with their own re-occurring workflow, that roll one daily, one monthly and the 3rd yearly, what in the workflow knows which of the database stored keys is associated with it (remembering another entity could have twice the number of scheduled workflows for same dates).  The issue is that each time the workflow rolls, there is no unique id for all the workflows linked from the same "parent", if that makes sense?

Comment: By "workflow rolls" are you talking about creating and running a new workflow instance or are you talking about running an existing workflow instance from persistence.  If the later then you store the Workflow ID as a key with the data key.

Comment: Hi Richard.  Apologies, not terms I can fully relate to, but I suspect it's the former in that I was relying of the "standard" MFW scheduling to reschedule a new occurrence of the task upon completion of the current one,  What I was attempting to do was to utilise "out of the box" scheduling functionality, and therefore avoiding building this within a workflow.  But if I can not pass a variable between system diarised tasks, even given that one initiates another, perhaps I have to.

Comment: .... As mentioned previously, the issue is that I can have multiple diarised events on the same record, hence use of re-occurring fields, if I cant connect a workflow to an instance/row, I'm stuffed.  I can create Workflows for each instance/row, which is fine until such time as someone deletes a record, and then this falls apart.